# Dynamic set CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am new in d3, I got some problem when I am trying to dynamic change element css, following is some example code:

```
#segment-list .segment div {
  display: inline-block;
  //width:150;        //1
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}


/////submit a .csv form 
<form>
....
<input style='font-size:15px' type='submit' name='submit' value='Go!' />
</form>
<script>
    $('#segment-list .segment div').css({
                                     'width': '150px' //2.will be a dynamic value, 150px just for example
                                        });
    d3.csv(filename, function(segments) {
        [create column by d3]
    }
</script>
```

The issue that I have is that if I pre-set <1> width property in `#segment-list .segment div` class, when .csv file uploaded the column size is loaded correctly. Whereas if set that later in script <2>, it seems column size is not set properly, like below[image: This is unexpected]

and pre-set 'width' result will be like:[image: Expected one]
So I am wondering is there a way to fix that, since dynamic width is needed, is there a way to set that element property first (or let say keep it value in `#segment-list .segment div` property, because that dynamic only depends on the form column number, so it just needs to be determined once at form submits moment ) then doing d3 rendering?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using .attr not .css ? var p = d3.selectAll("yourclass");
p.attr("width", 150); see: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection

Comment: Why use jquery at all if you can do this in D3 and just substitute 150 for a variable, making it dynamic.

Comment: @KristianVybiral cause I just start with d3...not quite familiar..but thanks! I am going to try that

Comment: How did it go, was my comment useful at all?